# Java servlet create cookie and then read from JSP is null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("user", "Test cookie");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
}
```

And I have a JSP:

```
    <% String name = request.getParameter("user"); %>
    <%= name%>
```

But if I run the code, the output is null, why?

Can you tell me why? What is easy way to get the "user" cookie.

Comment: Just a heads up, try to stay away from scriptlets when writing jsp

Comment: You set a session-scoped variable. You can use EL to access it in your JSP.  ${user}  Alternatively you could use a JSP expression <%=session.getAttribute("user")%>  This question has nothing to do with cookies.

Comment: As already said by the others, don't mix session and request, they're distinct scopes. However, you're storing data in the **session**, not in a cookie. If you really want a cookie (but there's probably no reason) you'll need something like `response.addCookie(new Cookie("user", "Test cookie"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `getAttribute(...)` not `getParameter(...)` like this :

```
 <% String name = session.getAttribute("user"); %>
```

Not.

```
<% String name = request.getParameter("user"); %>
```

- getParameter()  returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist.
- getAttribute() returns the value of the named attribute as an Object, or null if no attribute of the given name exists.
- Attribute, available for the life of the session.
- Parameter, only available for the life of the request

Answer (score 1):

> "But if I run the code, the output is null, why"?

If you have set the attribute on the **session**, that attribute does not exist on the request, hence the null returned from

```
 request.getParameter("user");
```

You need to get it from the **session** like so:

```
session.getAttribute("user");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implicit session object

`session.getAttribute( "user" );`

[Beginners book -jsp implicit-object-session](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-implicit-object-session-with-examples/)